# How to test if you can access your webserver from a public IP

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, webmin

My webserver running with Webmin/Virtualmin seems to be inaccessible from outside my LAN through it's public IP. How do I go around debugging and testing what's wrong and why I can't connect? I setup up port forwarding for port 80/443/10000

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You can see if the port is open with a firewall scanning tool (like GRC Shields Up!). Then you'll at least know if the port forward is ok.

Comment: Using many of the services found with Google that test port forwarding i can't get a single port stated as open no mather what settings i setup. I might have to contact my ISP.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a smart phone, you can use that as your "outside" source.  Just turn off the wi-fi and use only the cellular connection.  Open the browser app and point it to your public IP address.

Comment: Entering just the IP or the Webmin URL https://public-ip:10000 from mobile network results in a long load time until it times out. This is indeed a neat way to test things out from out side the LAN.

Comment: The next step is then to isolate the problem.  If you can access the web services from your **internal** network, then the issue is with your port forwarding setup.  If you suspect the problem is with your web server configuration, try this:  boot your computer to a Live Linux CD such as Knoppix or Ubuntu LiveCD, and turn on the web server with the defaults.  Use the same IP address that you have for your "real" web server, and try connecting from the outside.  If your port forwarding is set up correctly, you should be able to see the default web page.

Comment: I can infact access the server from my internal network through it's local ip. I have the server running in VirtualBox.

Comment: How can i test whether or not I can connect without having anything installed but the Ubuntu server? http://public-ip  ?

Comment: Even with DMZ enabled all ports i check show up as blocked or time out on websites that test for open ports.

Comment: What kind of networking do you have set up for your VM?  If you want to reach it from the outside, you're best off using bridged networking.

Answer (score 0):

I setup port forwarding to the PC running VirtualBox instead of the IP of the Server installation inside VirtualBox